# Как сделать чтобы консоль сразу считывала клавишу без нажатия enter?

Tags: c++

У меня есть такой кусочек кода. Пробовала getch(), но почему-то выходило 48+то число которое я нажала(если нажимаю 1 то выходит 49 и тд

```
 cout << "1 - go right" << endl
         << "2 - go left" << endl
         << "3 - fly" << endl
         << "4 - down" << endl
         << "5 - exit" << endl;
```

Comment: `int num = chr - '0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что это скан коды клавиатуры, и 49 это и есть скан код для 1, подробнее можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.jimprice.com/jim-asc.shtml#keycodes), там в главе **IBM PC Extended ASCII Display Characters** есть раскладка для Win, а таблица **Converting Hex to Decimal** поможет перевести коды

Answer (score 2):

А консоль в принципе не предназначена для получения клавиатурного ввода. Ввод всегда идет "как будто из текстового файла".

Некоторые терминальные клиенты по нажатию клавиш записывают в файловый дескриптор стандартного ввода некоторые контрольные последовательности, например [ansi-escape-sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php), [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). Их можно вычитывать (как текст) и интерпретировать.